# Fastest way to have JPEG pictures into a PDF document?

Tags: pdf

What would be the fastest way to have JPEG pictures into a PDF document?

I consider include graphics. Ideally, it would be great if a package could read the file content of a given directory, and create a list of JPEG files, and then use method to produce the pdf (fullwidth, one JPEG per page).

Best regards,

Comment: I think `\includegraphics` is your friend here. Do a Google search to find a way of expanding a picture along the page and for futher information.

Comment: Use `\includepdf{NameOfJpeg}` to get a full page of the image.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this. Requires `-shell-escape` in order to get a file list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processdir}{O{ls~-m~}mm+m}
 {% #1 = shell command, #2 = directory, #3 = pattern, #4 = template for processing
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__linuxn_process:n { #4 }
  \sys_shell_get:nnN { #1 #2/#3 } { } \l__linuxn_process_tl
  \clist_set:NV \l__linuxn_process_clist \l__linuxn_process_tl
  \clist_map_function:NN \l__linuxn_process_clist \__linuxn_process:n
 }

\tl_new:N \l__linuxn_process_tl
\clist_new:N \l__linuxn_process_clist
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__linuxn_process:n {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\processdir{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe}{*.jpg}{%
  \clearpage
  \noindent\parbox[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}{%
    {\centering\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{#1}\par}
    \bigskip
    \path{#1}
  }
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

The leading optional argument is for the flavor of `ls` you need: on Unix systems `ls -m` returns the file list with items separated by commas; adapt it for other systems.

[image]